# Passing arrays to a void function

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to print out the contents of array1 times 10 if the integer inside is positive, if it is negative , the number should be left as it is in an another array. My code doesn't give me any result, I'm not that good in programming so I'm pretty sure I'm making a stupid mistake but I can't make out what it is, can someone point out the problem

```
void
tenfold (int array2[], int size )
{
    int i, array1[size];
    for (i=0;i<size;i++)
{

    if (array1[i]>0)
        array2[i]= 10 * array1[i];


    else
        array2[i]= array1[i];
}
}

int main()
{
int i,array1[9]= {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, -8, -9, 1, 2};
int size = 9;
tenfold(array1, size);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tenfold should take array1 as input and array2 as local, other wise your are correct,
added a printf in tenfold to see the output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void tenfold (int array1[], int size )
{
    int i, array2[size]; 
    for (i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
         if (array1[i]>0)
                array2[i]= 10 * array1[i];
              else
                array2[i]= array1[i];
    }
   for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    printf("(orignal) array1[%d]=%d, (new) array2[%d]=%d\n", i, array1[i], i, array2[i]);
}

int main()
{
int i,array1[9]= {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, -8, -9, 1, 2};
int size = 9;
tenfold(array1, size);

return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
(orignal) array1[0]=3, (new) array2[0]=30
(orignal) array1[1]=4, (new) array2[1]=40
(orignal) array1[2]=5, (new) array2[2]=50
(orignal) array1[3]=6, (new) array2[3]=60
(orignal) array1[4]=7, (new) array2[4]=70
(orignal) array1[5]=-8, (new) array2[5]=-8
(orignal) array1[6]=-9, (new) array2[6]=-9
(orignal) array1[7]=1, (new) array2[7]=10
(orignal) array1[8]=2, (new) array2[8]=20
```

Answer (score 0):

You have changed the names of array in the function, update code to

```
//------------v array1
tenfold (int array1[], int size )
{
    int i, array2[size];  //here array2

    //your code
 }
```

With your code, `array1[]` is never initialized and has random values, so `if` will not work as expected.

Comment: Also this program never prints anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should first start by trying to printf the values in tenfold(). :-)
You don't need to create array1 in tenfold().

Also, you may be able to get away from using a size variable and just use sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]).

Comment: You definitely cannot avoid the size parameter to the function like that.

Answer (score 0):

tenfold doesn't print anything. There is no need to create another array if all you want if for that function to print. Be sure to add #include

```
#include <stdio.h>

void tenfold (int array[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if (array[i]>0)
        printf("%d ", (10 * array[i]));
      else
        printf("%d ", array[i]);

    }
}
```

output:
    30 40 50 60 70 -8 -9 10 20